# Debugging any C++ with Netbeans/gdb terminates immediately with a SIGSEGV?

Tags: c++, netbeans, gdb

My Os is : MacOS High Sierra  10.13.5

NetBeans Version : 8.2

Gdb Version: 8.0.1

I can use NetBeans build and run NetBeans Sample C++ Application successfully

but when I try to Use NetBeans to Debug NetBeans Sample C++ Application Quote with gdb, I always get an Error like below, and it always run into the osstream file, I am confused!

[image]

I set BreakPoint at main function like below
[image]

I don't change any configuration, It is NetBeans Default Configuration for sample C++ project Quote.

Anyone Can help me, how can I fix this error?

Comment: I strongly recommend removing the images, they are almost useless to us in answering your question, and replacing them with a [mcve]. To help you narrow the problem down to something manageable, a bus error often results from writing to read only memory. You wouldn't happen to be writing to a string literal, would you? Does `readChar` try to store data in the `char` pointer that was passed in?

Comment: "quote" is the sample app provided by netbeans, and I can build and run successfully. but when debug with gdb, I always get error immediately, wherever I set breakpoint, even I set  the breakpoint at the first line(cout ...) in main func.  I think it the netbeans or gdb's problem

Comment: Ah. That I cannot help with very much. Do you have similar results when you debug a simpler program? At 8.01 your GDB is quite up to date and GDB has historically behaved well with older versions of GCC. Could your GCC version have crept up above GDB?